# Proving if g(n) is o(f(n)), then f(n) + g(n) is Theta(f(n))

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, little-o

So I'm struggling with proving (or disproving) the above question. I feel like it is true, but I'm not sure how to show it.

Again, the question is if g(n) is o(f(n)), then f(n) + g(n) is Theta(f(n))

Note, that is a **little-o**, *not* a big-o!!!

So far, I've managed to (easily) show that:

g(n) = o(f(n)) **->** g(n) < c*f(n)

Then g(n) + f(n) < (c+1)*f(n)   **->**   (g(n) + f(n)) = **O**(f(n))

However, for showing Big Omega, I'm not sure what to do there.

Am I going about this right?

EDIT: Everyone provided great help, but I could only mark one. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far so good.

For the next step, recall that in the best case, `0 <= g(n)`; this should get you a lower bound on `g(n) + f(n)`.

Comment: Yeah, I considered adding another c*f(n) to both sides since we essentially want the form 

c1*f(n) < f(n) + g(n) < c2*f(n),

but that didn't feel right to do, as then we have additional constants in the middle, like 

c1*f(n) < (c1+1)f(n) + g(n) < (c1 + c2)*f(n), 

but that doesn't feel like a valid alteration, as the middle term should look exactly like we want it, right?

Comment: No, you have `f(n) <= g(n) + f(n)` from the fact the `0 <= g(n)`.  Combine that with the inequality you've already got, and you have lower and upper bounds...

Comment: Don't you need some general constant paired with the f(n) on the left hand side though to satisfy the conditions for Theta?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to take the limit of (f(n) + g(n)) / f(n) as n tends toward infinity. If this converges to a finite, nonzero value, then f(n) + g(n) = Θ(f(n)).

Assuming that f(n) is nonzero for sufficiently large n, the above ratio, in the limit, is

> (f(n) + g(n)) / f(n)
>
> = f(n) / f(n) + g(n) / f(n)
>
> = 1 + g(n) / f(n).

Therefore, taking the limit as n goes to infinity, the above expression converges to 1 because the ratio goes to zero (this is what it means for g(n) to be o(f(n)).

Comment: Oooh, I like this method a lot...and I'm guessing this works because you know f(n) and g(n) are both nonzero thanks to knowing g(n) is o(f(n))?

Comment: Oh, and how can we guarantee they are going to approach a limit? We just know one is strictly larger than another.

Comment: We actually only need f(n) to be nonzero, since it's the only one in the denominator. As for why g(n) / f(n) tends toward zero in the limit, you can actually show using the formal definition of a limit to infinity (the &epsilon;-n one) that if g(n) = o(f(n)), then lim g(n) / f(n) = 0 as n tends toward infinity. That explains why that second term disappears.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Before we begin, lets first state what little-o and Big-Theta notations means:

> *Little-o notation*
>
> Formally, that `g(n) = o(f(n))` (or `g(n) ∈ o(f(n))`) holds for
>   sufficiently large `n` means that for every positive constant `ε`
>   there exists a constant `N` such that
>
> ```
> |g(n)| ≤ ε*|f(n)|, for all n > N                                 (+)
> ```

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation.

> *Big-Θ notation*
>
> `h(n) = Θ(f(n))` means there exists positive constants `k_1`, `k_2`
>   and `N`, such that `k_1 · |f(n)|` and `k_2 · |f(n)|` is an upper bound
>   and lower bound on on `|h(n)|`, respectively, for `n > N`, i.e.
>
> ```
> k_1 · |f(n)| ≤ |h(n)| ≤ k_2 · |f(n)|, for all n > N              (++)
> ```

From https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-big-theta-notation.

---

***Given:*** `g(n) ∈ o(f(n))`

Hence, in our case, for every `ε>0` we can find some constant `N` such that `(+)`, for our functions `g(n)` and `f(n)`. Hence, for `n>N`, we have

```
|g(n)| ≤ ε*|f(n)|, for some ε>0, for all n>N

Choose a constant ε < 1 (recall, the above holds for all ε > 0), 
with accompanied constant N. 
Then the following holds for all n>N

    ε(|g(n)| + |f(n)|) ≤ 2|f(n)| ≤ 2(|g(n)| + |f(n)|) ≤ 4*|f(n)|    (*)
```

Stripping away the left-most inequality in `(*)` and dividing by 2, we have:

```
|f(n)| ≤ |g(n)| + |f(n)| ≤ 2*|f(n)|, n>N                            (**)
```

We see that this is the very definition Big-Θ notation, as presented in `(++)`, with constants `k_1 = 1`, `k_2 = 2` and `h(n) = g(n)+f(n)`. Hence

```
(**) => g(n) + f(n) is in Θ(f(n))
```

Ans we have shown that `g(n) ∈ o(f(n))` implies `(g(n) + f(n)) ∈ Θ(f(n))`.

Comment: Thank you for this in-depth answer. Everything together was really helpful!

Comment: @Wanna-beCoder Happy to help.